# Is the "equidistant curve" to an algebraic curve algebraic?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $ L \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a smooth real algebraic curve. Let's fix some parameter $ \delta \in \mathbb{R} $ and for every point $ (x,y) \in L $ define $$ L_{\delta}(x,y) = (x,y) + \delta n(x,y), $$ where $ n(x,y) $ is a normal vector to $L$ at $(x,y)$. The equidistant curve is then $$ L_\delta = \{L_\delta (x,y) : (x,y) \in L\}. $$

The idea is very simple: we take a normal vector with length $ \delta $ and "roll" it along the curve. Note that this is not the same as the set of points at the same distance $\delta$ from $L$.

I am trying to find the equation of $L$. But I do not even understand if it is algebraic. For example, let's consider the parabola $ L$ given by  $y - x^2 = 0 $. It is easy to find a parametrization of $ L_\delta $:
$$ x = t - \delta \frac{2t}{\sqrt{4t^2+1}}, $$
$$ y = t^2 + \delta \frac{1}{\sqrt{4t^2+1}}. $$
But how do I find the equation oh $x,y$ from this one? I looked up some literature about computational algebraic geometry. As I understood, there are only theorems for the case when the parametrization is rational in the variable $t$, which is not the case here. $ \mathbb{R} $ is not algebraicaly closed, maybe this is also an issue.

For me the question is interesting when $L$ is an algebraic surface in $ \mathbb{R}^n $, but the case of curves on the plane looks so simple that I am sure somebody has already solved it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What if $L(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$? What is the normal vector at the origin? No matter what you choose as $n(0,0)$, the set $L_\delta$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Please don’t make edits for single spelling mistakes, especially when there are other similarly obvious errors still to be corrected.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, $L_\delta$ is algebraic.  You can find its equations by elimination theory as follows:  Let $L$ be defined by the polynomial equation $F(x,y) = 0$.  Now consider the polynomial equations
$$
F(x,y)=(u{-}x)-aF_x(x,y)=  (v{-}y)-aF_y(x,y)= a^2(F_x(x,y)^2+F_y(x,y)^2)-\delta^2=0.
$$
for (x,y,a,u,v).  This is 4 equations for 5 unknowns.  You can now use elimination theory to find a polynomial equation $G(u,v)=0$ in the ideal of the above system of equations that does not involve $x$, $y$, or $a$.  This will be the algebraic equation of the parallel curve you want.

In your example of $y-x^2$, you find, for example, that the curve has degree $6$ and has the equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
0=&16\,{u}^{6}+16\,{u}^{4}{v}^{2}-40\,{u}^{4}v + \left( -48\,{b}^{2}+1
 \right) {u}^{4}\\
&\quad-32\,{u}^{2}{v}^{3}+ \left( -32\,{b}^{2}+32 \right) {u
}^{2}{v}^{2}+ \left( 8\,{b}^{2}-2 \right) {u}^{2}v+ \left( 48\,{b}^{4}
-20\,{b}^{2} \right) {u}^{2}\\
&\quad+16\,{v}^{4}+ \left( -32\,{b}^{2}-8
 \right) {v}^{3}+ \left( 16\,{b}^{4}-8\,{b}^{2}+1 \right) {v}^{2}+
 \left( 32\,{b}^{4}+8\,{b}^{2} \right) v\\
&\quad-16\,{b}^{6}-8\,{b}^{4}-{b}^{2
}
\end{aligned}
$$
where, to save typing, I have writteen $b$ instead of $\delta$.

**Remark:** If you apply this method to Willie Wong's 'counterexample', you get the equation
$$
0 = \bigl((u-v)^2-2b^2\bigr)\bigl((u+v)^2-2b^2\bigr),
$$
i.e., the equation of the 4 lines  $u\pm v = \pm b\sqrt2$, as expected.

Comment: Robert, thank you for your help! I have 3 questions:

1) Where can I read about this result from elimination theory? Eisenbud maybe?

2) Can you please describe, how exactly do you get your equation on u and v? May be this is the similar question as the previous one.

3) Can you say something about deg G, if you know deg F? For me it would be great, if there is some estimate. Again may be I just need to read some book about elimination theory...

Comment: @DanilSkuridin:  Eliminaton theory is a standard topic in old algebraic geometry books.  I think it is treated in Eisenbud, but you might also want to consult Cox, Little, and O'Shea's book, *Using algebraic geometry*.  I used the Groebner package in Maple to do the above calculation, but I'm sure that sage can do it as well.  There are lots of computer algebra systems around now.  I imagine that there is a standard way to compute the degree of $G$ from the degree of $F$ in the `generic' case, but I don't know it offhand.